# How can I inspect a XUL popup element without it disappearing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Firefox 31 broke my Googlebar Lite extension, and I'm trying to debug why. My problem is that mouse clicks no longer register for search suggestions that appear in the auto-complete popup menu (which comes as a part of the [Firefox autocomplete textbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Textbox_(Toolkit_autocomplete)) control). I'd like to inspect these chrome elements with [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/), but the popup closes (destroying the anonymous children) before I'm able to inspect them.

How can I inspect a popup element (in this case it's a [`panel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel)) without it disappearing? Is there a way I can force that kind of element to stay open so I can examine its children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the autocomplete DOM would require hacking deeply into the autocomplete code to avoid making it destroy items before inspecting.

While possible, I'd first look if the autocomplete code changed, so I tried:

- Finding the result interface on MXR: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/autocomplete/nsIAutoCompleteResult.idl
- Checking the log: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/filelog/de8c0f0e74a2/toolkit/components/autocomplete/nsIAutoCompleteResult.idl
- Checking out the newest changeset(s) and bug(s).
- And indeed, Bug 754265 amended the interface.

So I implemented the interface change, implementing the new API method, and after that the broken stuff works again:

```
getFinalCompleteValueAt: function(index) {
  return this._results[index];
},
```

I made a [pull-request](https://github.com/jgbishop/googlebarlite/pull/18) for you.

Comment: You, sir, are the man! I salute you and thank you for your efforts in tracking down this bug, and even providing a pull request for me. And thanks for providing a debug workflow; so much changes in Firefox from version to version that it's hard to keep track of it all. I'll merge your pull request later today.

Comment: I don't recommend this as a starting point.  The [Compatibility Tag](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/category/compatibility/) on Mozilla's blog is normally easier.  For Firefox 31, this would be [Add-on Compatibility for Firefox 31](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/07/03/compatibility-for-firefox-31/), which states, "...you will need to add a new function called getFinalCompleteValueAt..." along with links to documentation for how to do use it.  Checking this blog a couple weeks before each Firefox release is a good way to head off compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Also try installing addon "Element Inspector" it allows you Shift + Right Click anything and it pops it up in "DOM Inspector"

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/